# retrieve value using a combobox and send value to my txtbox thank you

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, textbox

Hi everyone I am trying to retrieve a value from my database using linq to Sql this is my code right now.
From a WPF i am taking a combobox value trying to retrieve a phone number from my microsoft sql server and the result gives me this  "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[MultiLoc.client]" in my txtbox.

```
        private void cmbIdClient_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VehiculeDataContext data = new VehiculeDataContext();

        List<client> clients = (from cli in data.clients select cli).ToList();
        IEnumerable<client> tel = Enumerable.Where(clients, x => x.id_client.ToString() == cmbIdClient.SelectedValue.ToString());
        txtnumerotel.Text = tel.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the output is `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator1[MultiLoc.client]` is due to `IEnumerable.ToString` only returns the type of the object, and not the values. Additionally, `IEnumerable` represents a collection of values, and not necessarily one value, which I don't think is what you want.

To resolve this, assuming that the `client` class looks something like:

```
public class client
{
    public int id_client { get; set; }
    public string phone_num { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And that each `client` has a unique `id_client`, you can change:

```
IEnumerable<client> tel = Enumerable.Where(clients, x => x.id_client.ToString() == cmbIdClient.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

To be:

```
string tel = clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id_client.ToString() == cmbIdClient.SelectedValue.ToString())?.phone_num ?? "<Whatever default value for no client>";
```